# Errores en las referencias de HTMLHelper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Visual studio me arroja  estos  errores que se ven en la imagen,ahún cuando tengo el codigo bien hecho y ademas cuando ejecuto la pagina todo anda bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esos errores te los arroja únicamente en los `HtmlHelper`?

Comment: también los viewbag y Scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recientemente he tenido el mismo problema lo que hice la ultima vez fue eliminar el contenido de la carpeta

`C:\Users\tuUsuario\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

Esos errores me sucedieron cuando hice una migración de proyecto `ASP .NET MVC 4` a `ASP .NET MVC 5` via `Nuget`.

---

**Esto es opcional ya que lo anterior puede funcionar a lo seguro**

Para corregir el error, tenía que cambiar manualmente la versión de `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` desde `2.0.0.0` a `3.0.0.0` en el web.config de las vistas:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

a

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Después de eso, la aplicación web se ejecuta bien, pero se quejó de que Visual Studio `@Model` no existe en el contexto actual. Esta vez tuve que cambiar todas las instancias de `System.Web.Mvc, Version = 4.0.0.0` a `System.Web.Mvc, Version = 5.2.3.0` , reinicie el Visual Studio, y reconstruir el proyecto.

**Referencia:**

http://www.dcaric.com/blog/the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context