# ¿Por qué no funcionan las extensiones de HtmlHelper de razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, razor

[image: Todas las extensiones de HtmlHelper de Razor no funcionan]

Me ha sucedido algo extraño, estaba trabajando con un proyecto MVC 5, y al subir cambios al repositorio, las extensiones de htmlhelper dejaron de funcionar en todo el proyecto, podrían ayudarme a solucionar éste error por favor, gracias.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro de haber padecido lo que mencionas usando Visual Studio 2015. En mi experiencia es un error que se soluciona luego de un momento. Prueba reconstruir la solución.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Errores en las referencias de HTMLHelper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/32612/6635)

Comment: Ya me había pasado que se ponían así las etiquetas en lo que cargaba el Visual Studio, pero ahora parece que se quedan así con el error permanentemente, baje la versión del proyecto en otra LapTop, y funciona perfecto, será algún problema del Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución, en el proyecto existen 2 WebConfig, el del proyecto en general, y otro en la carpeta de las Views, entonces vi que el la sección de "namespaces" del webconfig de las views no estaba la siguiente etiqueta

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
```

Al agregarla se soluciono, pues ya las extensiones de HtmlHelper encontraron su referencia.